# Failed capturing invoke command output in bash script as variable

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem with capturing the returning output from my invoke command.

```
peer chaincode invoke ...
```

I am using a bash script for calling the invoke command and I want to capture the terminal output in a variable.
[image: output]

In the end I need the ID from my minted items.

I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

As with any other bash script:

```sh
OUTPUT=$(peer chaincode invoke ...)
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

And then parse the output via regex (https://www.networkworld.com/article/2693361/unix-tip-using-bash-s-regular-expressions.html) or whatever you want.

Anyway, don't be lazy and use the SDKs... https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/fabric-sdks.html